# Git for Production got messed up with merging error

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull

My node_modules on production got messed up by another local machines with different node_modules. Now whenever `I git pull origin master` on production, the following messages displayed:

```
ubuntu@ip-:~/proj$ git pull origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa':
From bitbucket.org:laics/proj
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-complexity/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-concat/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-cssnano/node_modules/object-assign/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-cssnano/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-jsvalidate/node_modules/.bin/esparse
        node_modules/gulp-jsvalidate/node_modules/.bin/esvalidate
        node_modules/gulp-jsvalidate/node_modules/esprima/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-jsvalidate/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-less/node_modules/object-assign/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-less/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-ng-annotate/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-notify/package.json
        node_modules/gulp-rename/package.json
        .........
        node_modules/gulp-shell/node_modules/lodash/isEmpty.js
        node_modules/gulp-shell/node_modules/lodash/isError.js
        node_modules/gulp-shell/node_modules/lodash/isFunction.js
        node_modules/gulp-shell/node_modules/lo
   Aborting
```

It ends up the files that I want to update are not updated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you shouldn't check in the `node_modules` folder. Otherwise you have exactly that problem. Normally you have a script on your server which run that command on your server.

So remove the node_modules folder with

```
git rm --cached node_modules/
```

Then its removed from repo but still local on your computer. Then put it to your `.gitignore` and write a script which runs the install command when you push some changes or if your deploy your changes with a deployment system.